# Array_push to reference variable causing syntax errors

Tags: php, scope

Been quite some time since I did PHP; but, something that I believe used to work doesn't seem to be working PHP 7

```
$list = array ();
while ( ($data = fgetcsv($handle) ) !== FALSE ) {
  $row = array ();
  $row[0] = 1;
  array_push(&$list,$row);
}
```

This seems to fail due to "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&'" however if I take the & off the $list array won't have the $row array inside of it due to scope. Has this changed in PHP 7 on how to handle this?

Comment: try changing !== to != . You don't need the extra '=' for a Boolean comparison.

Comment: There shouldn't be a scope issue inside the example probably something else.

Comment: There's no need for `&`. Once you create a reference variable you just use it normally.

Comment: Take the & off then debug the script.

Comment: Call-time pass by reference has been removed in PHP 5.4 (iirc). Sounds like a really long time.

Comment: From your posted code, I can't figure out why you need to use a reference at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to push a reference to `$row`, it should be:

```
$list[] = &$row;
```

Reference syntax can't be used in function calls, only assignments. Assigning to an array followed by `[]` is equivalent to `array_push()`.